# How can I set up my Laptop as an extended second screen for my PC?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, extended-desktop

I do general programming support and operate with a screensharing software "GoTo Meeting". It'd really help my situation if I could have 2 monitors connected to my workstation (since all my work is recorded). My Dell Inspiron tower has one RGB and one HDMI port, which isn't a bad thing, but the monitor I have only supports RGB, which means that I need something to connect the HDMI to. Having one screen dedicated to my screenshare software would really boost my efficiency, but budgets don't give me the option to go and purchase another monitor, and I have no choice but to use this Inspiron tower for the office.

The only things I have that have an HDMI slot are an HP laptop and a Gateway laptop, both of which I have just reformated to Factory. Both are on Windows 7 Home, and the tower itself is Win8.

Is there a way I can set up an extension of my main Tower to support one of these laptops as the other screen?

I did some other checks around here but the various questions asked seem to be from years ago, and I'm hoping that options are available since then.

Comment: Anything wrong with ditching the tower and using the laptop as primary and extending it to a second monitor? A laptop's ports do not receive data in like a USB port, they always emit a signal as far as I know. So without software and a certain level of networking this is simply impossible.

Comment: well the laptops are mine personally, and the tower is the company's property. The higher ups are particular about information not crossing over to personal-use computers/devices. So much so, in fact, that we're provided with company-use USB sticks that are locked to work on our PCs only. I'd be all for the switchup, but I won't be given permission to have my personal computers linked up to the network for XYZ reasons.

Comment: Research points to this being a pricey task, pretty much impossible aside from gutting the laptop and reworking the video card or something. That's a bit much for me...i'd sooner invest in a new HDMI-compatible monitor. Just trying to put these laptops to good use at the office, if possible, before turning to my wallet.